# C# delegate parameter size

Tags: performance, parameters, delegates, size

I was wondering if C# delegates take up a similar amount of space that C pointers (4 bytes) do when passing to a method.

Edit

delegates only point to methods right? they can't point to structs or classes am i correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delegate only point to methods, one or more. 
The parameters must be similar to method.

```
public class Program
{
public delegate void Del(string message);
public delegate void Multiple();

public static void Main()
{
    Del handler = DelegateMethod;
    handler("Hello World");

    MethodWithCallback(5, 11, handler);

    Multiple multiplesMethods = MethodWithException;
    multiplesMethods += MethodOk;


    Console.WriteLine("Methods: " + multiplesMethods.GetInvocationList().GetLength(0));

    multiplesMethods();
}

public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

public static void MethodWithCallback(int param1, int param2, Del callback)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + (param1 + param2).ToString());
}

public static void MethodWithException()
{
    throw new Exception("Error");
}

public static void MethodOk()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method OK!");

}
```

}